# How to Fix Renderer Warnings in Android Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> Warning CS0618: 'PickerRenderer.PickerRenderer()' is obsolete: 'This
>   constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use
>   PickerRenderer(Context) instead.

This Warning is not only in picker renderer all renderers(Entry, DatePicker, StackLayout Renderer) are showing this warning. My custom renderer for Picker is like this,

```
 public class BorderlessPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {        
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var picker = e.NewElement;
            if (Control != null)
            {                             
                Control.Background = null;

                Control.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Pt, 8);

                Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#141414"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a new `.ctor` for `Xamarin.Forms` (2.5+) Android-based renderers  that accepts an Android-based context. The older parameterless constructor have been marked obsolete in order to support native embedding.

Add this to your renderer:

```
public BorderlessPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [2.5.0 release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.5/2.5.0-stable/) you should add a constructor the next way:

```
public BorderlessPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {}
```

In addition there is a [dedicated thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106938/context-is-obsolete-as-of-version-2-5) on official Xamarin forums on this topic.